# Image download function

Tags: php

So i made a image hosting site and im trying to add in a option to download the image. I have a s script and it works, just that all my images are stored in folders by date. so on the script its just a static url. How do i make this into like a function to add it into the actual image page, like "www.mysite.com/view-image/123456.png?download"

heres the code :

```
    <?php
 if (!$filename) {
        // if variable $filename is NULL or false display the message
        echo $err;
    } else {
        // define the path to your download folder plus assign the file name
        $path = 'image.uploads/' .$imagedate/'.$filename;
        // check that file exists and is readable
        if (file_exists($path) && is_readable($path)) {
            // get the file size and send the http headers
            $size = filesize($path);
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Length: '.$size);
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            // open the file in binary read-only mode
            // display the error messages if the file can´t be opened
            $file = @ fopen($path, 'rb');
            if ($file) {
                // stream the file and exit the script when complete
                fpassthru($file);
                exit;
            } else {
                echo $err;
            }
        } else {
            echo $err;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: so you are working on $path ? why not query right here and get the img  matching um? i dont know some id?

Comment: What do you mean? im new to php. Can you help me rewrite this? I need it to be able to code below the image. For ids, just make them up and ill change them

Comment: you said this is working? im confused with what u said, this is not working right? you are bearly building it

Comment: `I have a s script and it works`

Comment: can you try teamviewer with me?

Comment: its working but it only works if i go to www.mysite.com/download_file.php?file=Myimage.png. I need to implement this into the view-image.php page. so its like view-image/ah123n4.jpg?download

Comment: yea, we can do teamviewer.

Comment: ok this should be fun titanprofesia  -@- gmail DOT com send me a message

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you want files to be downloaded when a user navigates to the path..

You can use `.htaccess` to force download the file rather than viewing it in browser..

Comment: yea, i want to make a download button for users to download the image upon clicking the button

Comment: im seeing that he wants THIS script, so he wants to be able to call this script from the view-image file so he wants the functionality from download_file.php in that page, trouble is trying to call this link with the right image file name, which im guessing will be by some db query

Comment: You can make a download button with the target to the specific folder and add a .htaccess to it which will force download the file. Suppose the path is xyz/abc.png you can add .htaccess in xyz folder which will force download the abc.png image..

Comment: Hey, do u still want to team view me? i really need this done

Comment: @VladL yea email me so i we can share teamviewer info on private man check on the comments for the email: titanprofesia AT GMAIL